# Deserialize odata response without using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to fetch data from an OData url in a script component in an SSIS package. I have been trying to use Newtonsoft.JSON but the assembly doesn't load at runtime. The general resolution is to deploy the assemmbly to GAC or auto resolve the assembly by loading it from a location. I am not keen on doing that.

Is there a way in C# to fetch/deserialize data form an OData url, without using custom libraries/dlls?

Comment: Write your own if all else fails?

Comment: Have you looked at [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6620165/3744182) or [How to parse JSON without JSON.NET library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9573119/3744182)?  The answers there include several non-third-party libraries.

Comment: And as shown in the accepted answer to [How to deserialize oData JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26820355/3744182) you can use `HttpClient.GetStringAsync()` to download the raw JSON string.